# Can a Maven Plugin operate on JAR created as part of build

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I want to create a Maven plugin that will only be run after a release build of my jar.  The purpose is to identify all classes within my JAR that are annotated with a custom annotation.  It will then call a REST API with the details of these classes.

I have been looking at using javaparser to scan the source.  Is it possible to inspect the built jar file from a maven plugin.  That way i could use the Reflections library (getTypesAnnotatedWith) and it would make the process a bit easier.

Edit I have tried using Aether but am running into problems

```
package mypackage.maven.plugins;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
import org.apache.maven.repository.internal.MavenRepositorySystemUtils;
import org.eclipse.aether.DefaultRepositorySystemSession;
import org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem;
import org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession;
import org.eclipse.aether.artifact.Artifact;
import org.eclipse.aether.artifact.DefaultArtifact;
import org.eclipse.aether.collection.CollectRequest;
import org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException;
import org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.graph.Dependency;
import org.eclipse.aether.graph.DependencyNode;
import org.eclipse.aether.impl.DefaultServiceLocator;
import org.eclipse.aether.repository.LocalRepository;
import org.eclipse.aether.repository.RemoteRepository;
import org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactRequest;
import org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException;
import org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResult;
import org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.RepositoryConnectorFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.TransporterFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.transport.file.FileTransporterFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporterFactory;
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.Scanner;
import org.reflections.scanners.SubTypesScanner;
import org.reflections.scanners.TypeAnnotationsScanner;
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder;

import my.package.annotations.MyAnnotation;

@Mojo(name = "identify-checks")
public class MyCheckMojo extends AbstractMojo
{
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
    MavenProject project;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
    {                        
        RepositorySystem repoSystem = newRepositorySystem();

        RepositorySystemSession session = newSession( repoSystem );
        String coords = project.getGroupId() + ":" + project.getArtifactId() + ":" + project.getVersion();


        Dependency dependency = new Dependency( new DefaultArtifact(coords), "compile" );
        RemoteRepository central = new RemoteRepository.Builder( "central", "default", "http://myrepo:8081/nexus/content/repositories/" ).build();

        CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest();
        collectRequest.setRoot( dependency );
        collectRequest.addRepository( central );
        DependencyNode node;
        try
        {            
            node = repoSystem.collectDependencies( session, collectRequest ).getRoot();

            Artifact artifact = node.getArtifact();
            artifact.getArtifactId();

            ArtifactRequest artifactRequest = new ArtifactRequest();
            artifactRequest.setArtifact(artifact);
            ArtifactResult artifactResult = repoSystem.resolveArtifact(session, artifactRequest);
            artifact = artifactResult.getArtifact();

            ConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .addUrls(artifact.getFile().toURI().toURL())
                    .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include("my.package"))
                    .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false), new TypeAnnotationsScanner());

            Set<Scanner> scanners = configBuilder.getScanners();
            //SubTypesScanner = new SubTypesScanner(false);

            Reflections reflections = new Reflections(configBuilder);
                        //.setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(), new TypeAnnotationsScanner().filterResultsBy(myClassAnnotationsFilter)));
            Set<Class<?>> checks = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class, true);
            System.out.println("Number of checks is " + checks.size());
            for(Class<?> check : checks)
            {
                System.out.println(check.getName());
            }
            System.out.println("sdf");

        }
        catch (DependencyCollectionException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ArtifactResolutionException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static RepositorySystem newRepositorySystem()
    {
        DefaultServiceLocator locator = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newServiceLocator();
        locator.addService( RepositoryConnectorFactory.class, BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.class );
        locator.addService( TransporterFactory.class, FileTransporterFactory.class );
        locator.addService( TransporterFactory.class, HttpTransporterFactory.class );

        return locator.getService( RepositorySystem.class );
    }

    private static RepositorySystemSession newSession( RepositorySystem system )
    {
        DefaultRepositorySystemSession session = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newSession();

        LocalRepository localRepo = new LocalRepository( "C://maven_repository//repository" );
        session.setLocalRepositoryManager( system.newLocalRepositoryManager( session, localRepo ) );

        return session;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, either by referencing the artifact location (usually denoted by `${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}` properties) or by using [`ArtifactResolver`](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/index.html) in the plugin. You can take look at [Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin source code](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/maven-plugin/trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/maven/plugin/tomcat7/run/AbstractRunMojo.java?view=markup#l1527) which looks the artifact up from both local or remote Maven repository.

Do note that you must bind your custom plugin after `package` phase, usually in the `verify` phase.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I will have a look into this.  In terms of the phase that this runs, ultimately I will only want to run this after a release build.  We normally use a Jenkins job to kick this off.  Can i just add my maven plugin after the release, e.g. -Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform myplugin:dostuff

Comment: Yes, with this approach you should use the `ArtifactResolver` which will look up the released artifact from a repo.

Comment: Which maven dependency do I need to get the definitions for org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.ArtifactFactory and org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver?  I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I attempted to use the Aether to get the details.  However the Reflections library only loads what is on the classpath, and I don't want to have to add it to that of the plugin.  For the moment I have reverted to scanning the source code.  It feels as though there should be an easier solution to this but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @ceepan Reflections allows to set custom URLs (`ConfigurationBuilder.setUrls()`). You should be able to download the JAR from repo and create Reflections `Configuration` just for this single artifact.

Comment: I have tried using Reflections like you suggest but get no results. I have updated the original post with my code. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong please